# Locust export request and response body to csv file

Tags: python, locust

I'm reading data from .csv file for send api request.
And I want to export my failed requests and response bodies to .csv or .xlsx file.

This code is working fine but like I said i need request and response body.
I couldn't find true keyword in the @events.request_failure.add_listener.

Should i write new function for that? Like r.json() to csv file ?

Here is my code :

```
stat_file = open('stats.csv', 'w')
class MyUser(HttpUser):

    @task(1)
    def langdetect(self):
        customer = next(ssn_reader)
        r = self.client.post("/api/v1/customer", data=json.dumps({
            "text": f"/?ssn={customer[0]}"
        }),
                         headers=headers,
                         )
        print(r.text)        


# hook that is fired each time the request ends up with failure
@events.request_failure.add_listener
def hook_request_failure(request_type, name, response_time, response_length, **kw):
    stat_file.write(request_type + ";" + name + ";" + str(response_time) + ";" + str(response_length) + "\n")



@events.quitting.add_listener
def hook_quitting(environment, **kw):
    stat_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the new features in Locust 1.5 solve your issue? You can now add a free form ”context” as well as access the response in the request handler.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#request-context